# Derive the change of coordinates without using differentials

Tags: differential-geometry

Please forgive me for using the following lousy notations. I'm just a beginner in DG. Given two charts $(\psi,\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n),(\phi,\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ around a point $p$ in an n-dimensional manifold $M$, I'd like to derive the change of coordinates
$$\frac{\partial(f\circ\psi^{-1})}{\partial x_i}(\psi(p))=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial [r_j\circ(\phi\circ\psi^{-1})]}{\partial x_i}(\psi(p))\frac{\partial(f\circ\phi^{-1})}{\partial y_j}(\phi(p))$$
for $f\in C^\infty(M)$. Here $r_j$ denotes the $j$-th coordinate function that takes out the $j$-th component of a Euclidean vector. After consulting several textbooks, I found some solutions in terms of differentials or push-forwards. But what if I want to obtain the result by applying the chain rule **directly**? I couldn't come up with the details. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Yes that is done by chain rule directly. I do not even know if there is another way.

Comment: Thank you, but I have difficulty using the chain rule. Mappings that have subsets of 
a manifold as their domain or codomain really bother me.

Comment: What is your "chain rule" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That equation you wrote **IS** the multivariable chain rule, applied to the composition formula
$$f \circ \psi^{-1} = (f \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ (\phi \circ \psi^{-1})
$$

Comment: That's exactly what I want, and it really works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I shall follow the recipe by Lee Mosher, and this is for those beginners like me.

The chain rule states that if $g:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ and $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, then we have, at $a\in\mathbb R^m$,
$$\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial x_j}(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(g(a))\frac{\partial(r_i\circ g)}{\partial x_j}(a)$$
for $j=1,\ldots,m.$ Note that $r_i$ denotes, as usual, the $i$-th coordinate function. Now apply this to the composite $(f \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ (\phi \circ \psi^{-1})$, and something good will happen.